# Using grep within perl script and piping output to different files

Tags: perl, grep

I want to open a list of identifiers and find matches in another file. For this I used grep as a system function with a per script. But i am not sure where i am going wrong. Could you please help me out with the syntax? Thank you for your time!

```
open F, "$ARGV[0]" or die;
while(<F>)
{
    `grep -A1 "$_" CAM_PROJ_BATS.read.fa > $_.txt`;
}
```

Comment: What do you see that you're not expecting to see? What error (if any) do you get?

Answer (score 2):

If you were expecting output, you won't see any, because you aren't printing anything.  Add a print statement to see output.  (You may not need to see the output, but at least it will help you see errors with the grep command).

Also, the lines of your input file will have newlines at the end.  You probably don't want to pass that on to grep.  In fact, adding a newline may even be messing up the execution of your command on the shell.  Use `chomp` to remove newlines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open F, "$ARGV[0]" or die "Can't open file: $!";
while(<F>)
{
    chomp;
    print `grep -A1 "$_" CAM_PROJ_BATS.read.fa > $_.txt`;
}
```

(Not tested because I don't have grep).

Comment: Hey all,Thank you so much for your help. The print statement did it!